# warnings in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse

Can somebody please explain what does this warning mean: `undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'`?

Comment: Maybe this: http://www.peetm.com/blog/?p=278 ? It would be helpful to include the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google [has](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&goto=520513&) [lots](http://randomprogramming.sparkler.net/2009/04/undefined-reference-to-winmain16.html) [of](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread92830.html) [references](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/715077-error-undefined-reference-_winmain-16-when-compiling-cygwin) [to](http://www.gidforums.com/t-8754.html) that particular error. You need to provide a `WinMain` function, depending on what type of project you are building (console or Windows app).

Answer (score 0):

Quick google search shows:

http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/164498-linker-error-undefined-reference-winmain-16-a

> Banfa - Site Moderator
>
> `WinMain` replaces main as the entry point for Windows Applications so either you were trying to right [sic] a Windows application and left out WinMain or you wern't trying to write a Windows application and (hopefully) have a main but have compile/link with flags that tell the compiler/linker that this is a Windows application and probably linked with some of the Windows system libraries.